# Previously added Stream value to return on listen (Broadcast Stream)

Tags: dart

I have a custom `StreamController<int>`:

```
final StreamController listener = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
```

After initialization, I emit a value to the stream

```
listener.add(7);
```

*After emitting the value, I set a `Stream` listener*

```
listener.stream.listen((val) {
    print(val);
});
```

The expected behavior is that the listener will **return the previously set value**, however, that's not the case. Only if I set the value after I set the listener, the listener will be called.

How can I achieve that behavior?

(Edit: Multiple listeners have to be supported)

Comment: Don't make the stream a broadcast stream? The point of broadcast is to allow multiple listener but this will also throw away any events if there are no listeners: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html

Comment: @julemand101 okay nice solution, this worked. However, another requirement is that there can be multiple listeners. If you have a solution for that please consider writing an answer :)

Comment: Maybe call `asBroadcastStream` on the `Stream` returned from `StreamController`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html - "The returned stream will subscribe to this stream when its first subscriber is added, and will stay subscribed until this stream ends, or a callback cancels the subscription."

Comment: But yes, if you at some point returns to zero subscribers, the events will be throw away again. Another solution is to make something manually where you controls the list of subscribers yourself and put events into a buffer if there are no subscribers.

Comment: Well actually, there are a hint on `asBroadcastStream`: "Use the callbacks, for example, for pausing the underlying subscription while having no subscribers to prevent losing events, or canceling the subscription when there are no listeners."

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! Thank you for your help @julemand101. If you like you can write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't make the `Stream` a [broadcast stream](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html) since the definition of this kind of stream is to allow multiple subscribers but all events will be lost if there are no current subscribers.

Afterwards, take a look at the [`asBroadcastStream`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html) on the `Stream` returned from the `StreamController`. This method allows implementing logic where the Stream are first listened on after the first subscriber and also makes it possible to make logic like pause the stream if there are no more subscribers.

Comment: This only works for the first listener. The reason the stream controller was a broadcast one before was because it needs to be listened to by multiple listeners at the same time, which should all receive events when they start to listen. It does not matter if you use `asBroadcastStream` or a broadcast controller in that sense.

Comment: **a suitable alternative is [BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html) of RxDart, this class does exactly the work I've been asking for**

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `StreamController` `onListen` callback for it since it's gonna be called every time somebody subscribes.

```
class StreamExample {
  late final StreamController<dynamic> _controller;
  dynamic _val;

  StreamExample() {
    _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
    _controller.onListen = () => _controller.add(_val);
  }

  /// Example setter for value which works 
  /// like [ChangeNotifier] for [Stream] listeners.
  void set val(value) {
    _val = value;
    _controller.add(value);
  }

  Stream<dynamic> get stream => _controller.stream;
}
```